# Why I am getting Could not find multi_json-1.3.1 in any of the sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku, bundler

I have a simple Rails application I want to deploy to Heroku. When I run the below command

```
git push heroku master
```

The below error message is displayed.

```
 Could not find multi_json-1.3.1 in any of the sources
 !
 ! Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 ! Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
 gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
 gem 'pg'
 group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Delete the Gemfile.lock file, and run bundle install.
This works for me!

Comment: Also, don't forget to add and commit the changes to Gemfile.lock before pushing it after the bundle install. This seems obvious but I forgot to do it and of course, the error was the same when pushing ;)

Comment: On a project of any size you absolutely should _not_ do this. Deleting `Gemfile.lock` is the equivalent of a `bundle update` - i.e. updating every gem (without a fixed version) in your Gemfile at once. With a big enough Gemfile you're guaranteed to screw your whole project. Instead run `bundle update multi_json` to just get the latest version of that gem.

Comment: @jim Yes, i know! You solution works fine too and is more safe , thanks for replying!

Comment: Or even better bundle update --source multi_json. It will update *only* multi_json.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a series of these errors for different gems in spite of the fact I knew these gems were available (e.g. `gem list -r <gem>` showed them, including version; browsing rubygems.org showed the version I needed was there and hadn't been yanked etc) and I had a source set (I even set 6 different sources to be sure).

It turned out my problem was I had `git stashed` before leaving a feature branch to pull the latest on develop and forgotten to pop the stash afterwards, which was a problem because I had changed my `.rvmrc` and not committed the change (to use a newer ruby than our production did).

Because my `.rvmrc` specified a gemset for the project, stashing it meant I was suddenly bundling against a gemset that was missing a whole bunch of gems in my `Gemfile.lock` and for reasons I don't understand Bundler assumes if the gem is in `Gemfile.lock` it's already installed and it doesn't look it up remotely.

So just in case anyone else faces this incredibly frustrating corner case I thought I'd write it up here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Capistrano to do your deployments and you mysteriously get "Could not find multi_json-1.7.2 in any of the sources", ensure you have `require "bundler/capistrano"` at the top of your `config/deploy.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was lacking

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

in `Gemfile`. My suspicion is that old versions of bundler can operate without a source being mentioned, but newer versions can't.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused because Pow (local rack server) was not using the correct RVM ruby version/gemset.

Fixed by adding the following `.powrc`:

```
# based on https://coderwall.com/p/pkj39a
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".ruby-version" ] && [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
  rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`cat .ruby-gemset`
fi
```

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/pkj39a

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it by the following steps.

```
Removed Gemfile.lock
bundle install
```

The cause of the problem is initially my Gemfile.lock has multi_json-1.3.1

Now it has the version multi_json-1.3.2